# how to get country name from latitude and longitude

Tags: c#, bing-maps

How can i get the country name from latitude and longtitude using c#?
Im using the Bing.Map API

```
Location location12 = new Location(location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
MapLayer.SetPosition(pin, location12);
Map.Children.Add(pin);
string placeName = GetPlaceNameForCoordinates(location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
```

Comment: Is this using the Bing.Maps API? It would be worth making that clear in your question.

Comment: yes using Bing.Maps API

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use a reverse geocoding API of some kind. For example:

- The [Bing Maps API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ff701710.aspx) (the webservice)
- The [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)
- The [Geonames API](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html)

If you're already using the Bing.Maps SDK, you should use the `Map.SearchManager` property to get a [`SearchManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn306041.aspx), and then use the `ReverseGeocodeAsync` method. In particular, as noted in comments, mixing and matching which API you use to show data via other SDKs may well violate the terms and conditions of both: be careful which technologies you use within a single application. (Even though this question gives sample code using the Bing Maps SDK, I've kept the list above in order to help others who may come with a slightly different context.)

For example:

```
var manager = map.SearchManager;
var request = new ReverseGeocodeRequestOptions(location) {
    IncludeEntityTypeFlags = ReverseGeocodeEntityType.CountryRegion
};
var response = await manager.ReverseGeocodeAsync(
    new ReverseGeocodeRequestOptions(location) { );
// Use the response
```

If you decide to use the Geonames API, the data can be downloaded for offline use too.

Comment: Just a quick tip. Mixing Google API's with Bing Maps is against the terms of use of both platforms. It's best to stick with the Bing Maps API's when using the Bing Maps control. It will also make things much cheaper if this is a production app that requires a license.

Comment: @rbrundritt: Good point, I wasn't aware of that. Will edit to make that clear, while maintaining the list for other users who may not be in quite the same boat.

Answer (score -1):

I've created a github project with sample code that does this without api calls

see [here](https://github.com/InquisitorJax/Wibci.CountryReverseGeocode)

Very simple country name and id returned